# Storage options for win 8/10 universal app?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, win-universal-app, windows-10

Assuming I want to develop a Win 8/10 universal app eg calendar, the user has a two devices tablet/phone.

How can my calendar share a local SQL database?

I don't want to maintain or administer an azure service or any other remote DB service ie AWS, VPS running SQL Express etc.. which is overkill for such a basic scenario.

I have considered SQLite and dumping the DB file in the users MS OneDrive folder but as we know this could result in sync/lock issues.

So using a purely self contained & free model, how can my two devices share this basic SQL data?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to choose between using a server-side database (single source of truth) or having multiple client-side databases that you try and synchronize (possibility of conflicts). There isn't really anything in-between.

Answer (score 1):

If the database is small you can save it in the RoamingFolder and let Windows take care of copying it to the other system.

See [Quickstart: Roaming app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700362.aspx)

Other than that storing the data in a cloud service such as an [Azure Mobile App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) is the easiest and cleanest solution. Azure Mobile Services support [offline sync to SQLite](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/30/offline-sync-for-mobile-services/) if you need to support both online and offline scenarios.

Saving app data on the user's OneDrive or dropbox and then explicitly downloading it to use is possible but more difficult and a bit dirtier since the data will be visible to the user and could be accidentally deleted, moved, etc. For a personal app it's not bad but I wouldn't do this in production.

If you're copying the database between systems (either via roaming or via a data storage site) you'll need to devise a way to handle conflicts. This is simpler if everything is kept in a single cloud database.

Comment: Thank you, it's a shame this scenario can only be addressed with an azure solution which really is overkill. I get where MSFT are going though with services business model. Think I may use a VPS running SQL for now & create an API, I can control the costs more effectively.

Comment: Roaming app data looked good for a moment but as you say its small, its 100KB! wow that is small. To be fair its for settings so not really appropriate for a database.